# .NET 7 Console application standalone executable for Windows, Linux and MacOS

Tags: c#, .net, cross-platform, publish, .net-7.0

How can I create a standalone executable file for Windows, Linux and MacOS and how can I run it on the particular OS?

I tried publishing it as Self Contained and standalone file but I still got tons of dlls.

Can anyone help?

Comment: Using Core automatically allows an application to run without changes on Windows, Linux, and Mac.  That was the whole purpose of switching from Net to Core.  When you publish a Core application the runtime library is automatically installed on the deploy machine.  Check you target version of Net/Core and make sure it is Core.  Are the errors you are getting is a Net/Core library or for one of your child projects?

Comment: The runtime was not automatically installed and the program did not run.

Answer (score 0):

Add "PublishSingleFile" in your project file and set it to "True" value.
for more information check this link:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/deploying/single-file/overview?tabs=cli#publish-a-single-file-app

This information can also be helpful for your project.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/deploying/native-aot/?tabs=net7

Comment: This unfortunately did not work either for Linux